# How can I hide a certain warning message showing to users?

Tags: 6

I would like to hide the following warning message from users when they submit a web form. I know when this warning message shows up and don't really need to fix it but just want to hide it from users.

```
warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /public_html/sites/all/modules/phpmailer/includes/phpmailer.drupal.inc on line 33.
```

I tried [Disable message module](http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) but it's only for the Drupal system error message.
Is there anyway to hide a certain warning message just like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On admin/settings/error-reporting, you set where the messages generated by PHP warnings/errors are shown.

[image: screenshot]

When you select *Write errors to the log and to the screen* for *Error reporting*, such errors are shown on the screen, and saved in the database table containing the error messages; when you select *Write errors to the log*, the errors are not shown on the screen.

[drupal_error_handler()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_error_handler/6) is the error handler set by Drupal in [_drupal_bootstrap_full()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_full/6). The code that shows the message, and/or saves them in the database is the following one.

```
// Force display of error messages in update.php.
if (variable_get('error_level', 1) == 1 || strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'update.php')) {
  drupal_set_message($entry, 'error');
}

watchdog('php', '%message in %file on line %line.', array('%error' => $types[$errno], '%message' => $message, '%file' => $filename, '%line' => $line), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `ini_set( 'display_errors','0');` in your setting.php file in drupal site.

See more about error reporting 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)

```
ini_set( 'display_errors','0');
```